# How do I set ParallelScope for Parametrized Test classes in NUNit?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, nunit

I've got test suite containing two test classes and one base class for parallel scope:

```
[TestFixture("A")]
[TestFixture("B")]
class Fixture1 : BaseFixture{
//tests}

[TestFixture("A")]
[TestFixture("B")]
class Fixture2 : BaseFixture{
//tests}

[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
class BaseFixture{
}
```

With this parallelization scope my tests run like scenario 1 [in given schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHGnG.png). **I dont want parallel execution for different data.**
With [NonParallelizable] attribute in Fixture1 and Fixture2 I reach scenario 2 - **that's a serious bottleneck for performance of test.**

All I want is keep **parallelization between classes**, but **not between different data for class**, like presented on scenario 3 in schema.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, there is no way to designate that a fixture can run in parallel with some fixtures, but not others. At one time it was a feature we planned to implement, but I am not sure it's still on the roadmap.

Do you want the individual tests within each fixture to run in parallel? Depending on the answer, there are different courses of action you may take as a workaround.

1. Run the test cases in parallel and the allow the fixtures to simply run sequentially. If there are enough cases, that may give you "good enough" throughput.
2. Run the test cases sequentially and let the fixtures all run in parallel. To do that, you have to modify them to make sure they don't try to use the same driver or share any other state.

Sorry it's not a better answer. :-)

Comment: 1. Tests inside fixture has to run sequentially, so that solution does not satisfy me :(
2. That's what I am currently doing, it looks like I have to accept slowing down my tests

Anyway, thanks for your help Charlie. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating the `TestFixture` attribute duplicates the test fixture, which is why the fixtures run in parallel. There does not seem to be a solution to get the two fixtures to run in parallel.

You can use `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Default)]` to override the parallelization on all test fixtures that use test data. This will run those fixtures sequentially while allowing all other test fixtures to run sequentially.

Comment: If you look at the code, you'll see that the `Default` option is non-browsable. We did that to protect you from using something that is not useful and may disappear in future. It's entirely equivalent to use of `[NonParallelizable]', which is the advertised and recommended approach. In this case, of course, it doesn't solve the stated problem anyway.